# How can I share my clipboard between two X servers?

Tags: xorg, clipboard

I've recently set up my Ubuntu machine so that I run another X session in pty8.  I mostly run virtual machines or remote desktop sessions on this other X server, which helps mediate some of the frustrations that can happen with keyboard integration in these environments.

However, now if I copy something from some window on :0, I can't paste it into some window on :1.

Is there a way I can share the clipboard between these two sessions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came up with a solution that seems to work pretty well.  I'm not sure if there's a better way, but I wrote a script that starts my VM and then monitors the clipboard on display :0 for changes.  When a change is detected, it copies the clipboard contents to display :1.  It does this bidirectionally, so I can copy and paste from the VM just fine too.

Here's the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

virtualbox --startvm "Windows 7" --fullscreen &
waitpid=$!

watch_clip() {
  local curr="" prev="" from=$1 to=:0

  # On first run, we need to copy from :0 to :1 but not vice versa
  if [[ "$from" == ":0" ]]; then
    xclip -o -selection clipboard -d :0 2> /dev/null | xclip -selection clipboard -d :1
    to=:1
  fi

  while true; do
    # Get the current clipboard contents
    curr=`xclip -o -selection clipboard -d $from 2> /dev/null`

    # Compare to previous results and copy if it's changed
    if [[ "$curr" != "$prev" ]]; then
      echo "$curr" | xclip -selection clipboard -d $to
    fi

    prev="$curr"   
    sleep 0.5
  done
}

watch_clip :0 &
watch_clip :1 &
wait $waitpid
```

Then all that's needed is the command to start the second X session:

```
startx ./.startwin7 -- :1
```

I haven't noticed any issues, but if anyone can think of a better way I'd definitely appreciate the input.

Comment: Your post gave me an idea and I've simplified your script to this: `xclip -selection clip -o -display :0 | xclip -selection clip -i -display :1` (see http://superuser.com/a/992418/19223)

Answer (score 3):

If you want something turnkey, [Synergy](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/synergy/) should do the trick. I've never used it on just one box, across X sessions. It works to share clipboards between separate machines, so it would be surprising if a design flaw or usability issue kept it from working for you.

Also: for your vms, they have builds [for Mac and Windows](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/synergy/).

Comment: +1. That's pretty cool, I had seen something like that in my searches and was just hoping there was something that didn't require any setup.  The only issue I've considered from my own solution is if someone logs into the guest account on my laptop before I login or start my virtual machine.  That hasn't happened yet, but if it does become a problem then I might look into using Synergy to synchronise the clipboard instead.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer.  I've awarded the bounty, but I decided to go with my own answer for the accepted solution as it is closer to what I was looking for, and I haven't had any problems with it thus far.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is interesting; do what works for you though, right? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Synergy didn't work well for me (it has major bugs in the X11 part of its clipboard syncing), and I didn't want to have a script that just polls the clipboard with a time delay, as that wastes CPU and/or adds random delays before I can paste.  I wrote a script called xclipsync that solves the problem for me.

https://github.com/apenwarr/xclipsync